# Truffle Serve error

Tags: truffle

```
Serving static assets in ./build on port 8080...
Rebuilding...
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:144626
  return (new fsevents(path)).on('fsevent', callback).start();
          ^

TypeError: fsevents is not a constructor
    at createFSEventsInstance (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:144626:11)
    at setFSEventsListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:144680:16)
    at FSWatcher.FsEventsHandler._watchWithFsEvents (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:144844:16)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:144978:25)
    at LOOP (fs.js:1753:14)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

npm run dev is also not working for me.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@5.3.0
3 info using node@v8.2.1
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: dev
4 verbose stack     at run (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:151:19)
4 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:61:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:114:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:401:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:356:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:399:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:159:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:331:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:420:13)
5 verbose cwd /home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE
6 verbose Linux 4.4.0-87-generic
7 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
8 verbose node v8.2.1
9 verbose npm  v5.3.0
10 error missing script: dev
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

please help! I have understood the error. I require some script in the dev tag in the package.json file. Now can someone tell me what that needs to be?

Answer (score 1):

npm uninstall -g truffle

npm install -g truffle@3.2.1

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering this question. Can you please add some comments to your answer?

Comment: Because truffle version

Answer (score 0):

I was using Truffle v3.3.0 when I had the same issue with fsevent bundling; Resolved it by using Truffle v3.2.1:

> npm install -g truffle@3.2.1

Seems to still be an issue for some:
https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/448

Let us know if this doesn't help? (rep<50 else I would have left a comment which should be more appropriate)